# Private note-taking/syncing software that supports Linux and Android

Tags: linux, android, note-taking, privacy, synchronization

Are there any programs out there that:

- Allows me to take notes (preferably including multimedia)
- Syncs notes between clients without using a server not controlled by me*
- Supports Linux and Android (and other OSs, if possible)?
- The data format should be open, preferably standardised, and ideally text-based (markdown?).

* I'm happy to run my own light-weight server, but P2P would be preferable. I'm not interested in web-based note-taking software.

Answer (score 3):

**[ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/)** can be setup on your Linux machine. It supports a lot more than just notes (I use it e.g. for my calendars and contacts, so no Google here for that).

Then there are several apps supporting the *ownCloud* notes components, e.g. [My Own Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.aykit.MyOwnNotes) (also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.aykit.MyOwnNotes)) and [MortNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.mortnotes). I have not used the notes component with Android yet, just on the "Linux end": *ownCloud* runs as a web service, so you can access (and edit/organize) your contacts, calendars, notes, etc. from within a web-browser anywhere. The notes component supports [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), which not only gives you the possibility to well-structure your documents, but also to include/link to multimedia files.

To match this solution against your requirements:

- it allows you to take notes, to a degree with multimedia as well
- syncs without the need of a third party's server
- Supports Linux and Android, and many other OSses (as long as they have a browser and a network connection, you could at least always fall-back to that ;)
- The data format is open, and even better: it is Markdown.

As you write, you're "not interested in web-based note-taking software." I hope you don't mind if that is avaiable, too – as long as you have the other parts covered as well :)

I'm sorry I must pass on the Linux editor here. I'm pretty sure there was one, but never having the need for it, I don't remember which one it was. As *ownCloud* also supports, to a degree, OpenOffice/LibreOffice documents (read and write), I could name those; but you couldn't call them "light-weight"... As *ownCloud* supports [WebDav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), you could use that to access your files (including the notes), and use an editor like [ReText](https://sourceforge.net/projects/retext/) – which offers a live preview to see what you type, PDF export, and more – of course, working with *Markdown*. I'm using this editor (and can recommend it by heart), but I've not tried to access *ownCloud* notes this way – so I cannot tell for sure how that works together (but am confident it does well).

Comment: +1, covers most of the bases, but I have looked in to it before, and it feels like overkill for what I want. I might go and check it out again at some point though.

Comment: If you feel that an overkill, you could just go with any leight-weight WebDav server – and *ReText* on Linux plus *MortNotes* on Android. That might remove the "Web FrontEnd from anywhere" option, though.

Comment: Yeah, that might be worth a go. Not really interested in a web front end, if I can access it from any device anyway - it's just one more avenue for security holes.

Answer (score 1):

### Bittorrent Sync

[BTSync](http://www.getsync.com/download) covers all your bases. You can sync what you want and how much you want, limited only by your bandwidth and hard drive space. No real dependence on 3rd-party servers, and cross-platform. This way you can use any program that has a version or compatible app for the platforms you want to interoperate with. Works over LAN as well, and transfers are encrypted.

Comment: Yeah, but syncthing does the same thing, and it's open source.

Comment: I didn't like syncthing and don't really recommend it yet.

Comment: They do basically the same thing - here's a [basic comparison](https://discourse.syncthing.net/t/how-is-pulse-different-to-bittorrent-sync/1083). (note pulse==Syncthing). What would cause you not to recommend it over BTSync?

Comment: It was months ago when I tried it, but it wasn't very polished and had issues I don't recall off the top of my head. It was more difficult to connect devices. Connection didn't work in some situations where it would "just work" with BTSync.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't had those problems, but connecting devices using the (very long) has can be a bit annoying. Discovery over local networks seems to work now though.

Comment: I'll probably give it another go when I'm in a position to test again, but I can't recommend it until I do. I'd prefer if BTSync was open source, but at least it does the job better than anything else I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this because it does work, and I haven't yet seen a better option.

### [syncthing](http://syncthing.net/) + [vim](http://www.vim.org/)

I'm already used to using vim to edit text files, so that gives me my todo list and notes. Vim is available for Linux/Windows/OSX and other desktop OSs.

[VimTouch](https://github.com/momodalo/vimtouch) (available via the F-droid and the PlayStore) works surprisingly well on android, even without a physical keyboard.

Syncthing is a a P2P sharing app that works in a similar way to BTSync, but is completely open source. Syncthing is available for Linux/Windows/OSX and other desktop OSs, and there is a third-party android app available via F-droid and the PlayStore.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using NoteCase Pro (http://www.notecasepro.com).
If features its own sync server application that you can run on your own PC.
Note that Android synchronization is in the works, but you can test sync feature on desktop.

Program is cross platform (Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD, Solaris, Android), multi-language, supports rich text, tagging, tasks, attachments, spellchecking, 
encryption, custom features using scripts/plugins. And it imports files of many other outliner programs.